# How do you use FFMPEG to transcode h264_qsv from Apple PRORES Quicktime?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to transcode an Apple Prores 444 to H.264 using qsv without success.

If I use this command line:

`ffmpeg -i 10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac -pix_fmt qsv  chris.mp4`

I get:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537134592
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-12-19T12:43:38.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.author: 
    com.apple.quicktime.comment: 
    com.apple.quicktime.copyright: 
    com.apple.quicktime.description: 
    com.apple.quicktime.director: 
    com.apple.quicktime.genre: 
    com.apple.quicktime.information: 
    com.apple.quicktime.keywords: 
    com.apple.quicktime.producer: 
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: 
    timecode        : 12:43:37;28
  Duration: 00:10:06.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 167429 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-04T00:49:14.000000Z
      timecode        : 12:43:37;28
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(tv, GBR, progressive), 1280x720, 164985 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:04.000000Z
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-10-05T11:26:56.000000Z
File 'chris.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_qsv @ 0x56265b81a800] Selected ratecontrol mode is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x56265b81a800] Low power mode is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x56265b81a800] Current frame rate is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x56265b81a800] Current picture structure is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x56265b81a800] Current resolution is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x56265b81a800] Current pixel format is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x56265b81a800] some encoding parameters are not supported by the QSV runtime. Please double check the input parameters.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
user@NUC:~$ ffmpeg -i 10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac -pix_fmt qsv  chris.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537134592
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-12-19T12:43:38.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.author: 
    com.apple.quicktime.comment: 
    com.apple.quicktime.copyright: 
    com.apple.quicktime.description: 
    com.apple.quicktime.director: 
    com.apple.quicktime.genre: 
    com.apple.quicktime.information: 
    com.apple.quicktime.keywords: 
    com.apple.quicktime.producer: 
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: 
    timecode        : 12:43:37;28
  Duration: 00:10:06.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 167429 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-04T00:49:14.000000Z
      timecode        : 12:43:37;28
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(tv, GBR, progressive), 1280x720, 164985 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:04.000000Z
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-10-05T11:26:56.000000Z
File 'chris.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!
```

If I use:

`ffmpeg -i 10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac  chris.mp4`

I get:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537134592
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-12-19T12:43:38.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.author: 
    com.apple.quicktime.comment: 
    com.apple.quicktime.copyright: 
    com.apple.quicktime.description: 
    com.apple.quicktime.director: 
    com.apple.quicktime.genre: 
    com.apple.quicktime.information: 
    com.apple.quicktime.keywords: 
    com.apple.quicktime.producer: 
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: 
    timecode        : 12:43:37;28
  Duration: 00:10:06.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 167429 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-04T00:49:14.000000Z
      timecode        : 12:43:37;28
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(tv, GBR, progressive), 1280x720, 164985 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:04.000000Z
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-10-05T11:26:56.000000Z
File 'chris.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!
user@NUC:~$ ffmpeg -i 10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac  chris.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537134592
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-12-19T12:43:38.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.author: 
    com.apple.quicktime.comment: 
    com.apple.quicktime.copyright: 
    com.apple.quicktime.description: 
    com.apple.quicktime.director: 
    com.apple.quicktime.genre: 
    com.apple.quicktime.information: 
    com.apple.quicktime.keywords: 
    com.apple.quicktime.producer: 
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: 
    timecode        : 12:43:37;28
  Duration: 00:10:06.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 167429 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-04T00:49:14.000000Z
      timecode        : 12:43:37;28
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: prores (Standard) (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(tv, GBR, progressive), 1280x720, 164985 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:04.000000Z
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2003-10-05T11:26:56.000000Z
File 'chris.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_qsv @ 0x55b3bb6e8800] Selected ratecontrol mode is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x55b3bb6e8800] Low power mode is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x55b3bb6e8800] Current frame rate is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x55b3bb6e8800] Current picture structure is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x55b3bb6e8800] Current resolution is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x55b3bb6e8800] Current pixel format is unsupported
[h264_qsv @ 0x55b3bb6e8800] some encoding parameters are not supported by the QSV runtime. Please double check the input parameters.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

I cannot get ANYTHING to work. I can transcode other h264 files without issue. I cannot seem to transcode this prores file.

Here is a link to the source file if anyone can help I would REALLY appreciate it...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejrfzad20yzaifm/10minute_Pipeline_Test.mov?dl=1

Comment: (please check 3rd party edits of your post - e.g., is *H.264 files* what you intended where you posted `h264 feels`?)

Comment: Yes.. That is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I use H264_QSV daily, and I find you have to declare the QSV device as being available.

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -hide_banner -loglevel verbose -init_hw_device qsv:qsv,child_device_type=qsv ^ -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i "input.mov" -q:v 30 -preset slow -c:a aac output.mp4
```

There are many more options that can be added to improve efficiency, change the quality (the -q:v setting), etc.

I've found that QSV speeds things up so much that you can use a -preset of slow or very slow to get more compression for a given quality setting without significantly increasing the time it takes to convert the file.

Comment: Is this really `h264_qsv`? logs when running this command show `libx264` and I don't see `-c:v h264_qsv` in the command.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have done the copy as well as I should have.

This is a more complete copy of how I use ffmpeg.

ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -hide_banner -loglevel verbose -stats -benchmark -init_hw_device qsv:qsv,child_device_type=qsv ^
-hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv   ^
-i "input file"  ^
-c:a aac -q:a 1.9 -strict normal -sws_flags lanczos ^
-vf "vpp_qsv=cw=704:ch=480:cx=11:cy=0:w=640:h=480" ^
-async_depth 128 -q:v 28 -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryslow (a bunch of optimization options on how I want the compression to be done go in here, which can be discussed separately) -movflags +faststart "output file.mp4"

This is on Windows so the carat "^" is the command line continuation character.

-err_detect suppresses some of the more useless messages.  -hide_banner suppresses things that I normally don't need to see at all.

-loglevel is usually set to "info" or "quiet", but if you want to know exactly which codecs are being used, set it to "verbose" as it is here.
This is the simple answer to the original question, "Am I using the QSV codec?".

-strict normal is optional, but I found some applications didn't do well with some of the newer optimizations.  It does not appear to increase file size to any significant extent, and I don't run into problems running videos on old equipment.

I put the audio processing first as it seems to work better that way.
I let the codec choose the bit rate by setting the quality, as with the video (see below).

I have also included an example of the vpp_qsv video processing filter, as I find it speeds up many operations.  It can, of course, be left out if you don't need it.  I put it before the compression codec:  ffmpeg will process them in the proper order, but I find it's easier to keep track of what's going on if I put the commands in about the same order as they will eventually be processed.  When I put the commands in this order and "verbose" is on, ffmpeg reports that the output of the vpp_qsv filter remains in video memory as the input to the h264_qsv codec.  This speeds things up in my tests: or, at least, it reduces the CPU load so other programs can run at the same time.

-async_depth is optional, increases the number of frames that are read before compression is done; I find this also usually makes things go a bit faster. -q:v is the compression quality setting: I've found 28 to 30 gives me good results for watching videos on a reasonably large TV, but you will have to make tests for yourself to see what setting is right for you. Doing this is much, much better than guessing what bitrate you need, the codec can do better optimizations, and so on.  You will, in most cases, get variable bit rate compression, and sometimes variable frame rates. This improves compression for parts of the video that don't have much going on, while still providing higher bit rates when needed. You may be surprised at how low a bit rate can be produced this way and still have a good quality video.

I put -movflags +faststart in ALL of my MP4 videos.  This moves a copy of the MOOV atom from the end of the video to the beginning. This does at least two things.  First, for many players, the video will start playing faster as the information the player needs about the video is read immediately. Second, if an MP4 file ever gets truncated and the MOOV atom is missing, you will not be able to play the file at all.  There are programs that pretend to be able to recover the missing information, but I have yet to see one actually work.  But if the MOOV atom is also included at the beginning of the video, you will at least be able to start processing the video, and should at least get to the point where the file is damaged.  It's cheap insurance, and only takes a moment or two.  (This won't work if your output is a live stream, the video has to be "finished" before the atom is created.)

-stats and -benchmark are optional, I like to see how fast processing is going and be able to compare it to other times I process videos to see if any changes I make to the options are helping or not.

If there is an interest in the various vpp_qsv filter options, or in what other compression settings I use, or what settings will allow videos to work with Roku Media Player, let me know which topic I should post that in.